# Чат на сокетах

Tags: java, сокет

Привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста. Допустим (именно допустим, т.к его нет), есть чат который работает на сокетах. Пользователи через приложение подключаются к серверу (192.168.1.53:80). Не могу понять, как в случае с сокетами дать возможность пользователям создавать на этом сервере так сказать свои комнаты, для разговора. Я что-то туплю по страшному, но в голову ничего не лезет. ЯП не важен, я именно логику по которой правильно делать разделение понять не могу и найти тоже.

Comment: @Sever, а что подразумевается под "комнатой для разговора"? 

Вы бы протокол (набор команд, которыми клиенты и сервер обмениваются по сокетам) обрисовали для начала.

Тогда можно что-то советовать.

Comment: @avp, пользователь создает так сказать "комнату", чтобы общаться только с определенным кругом других пользователей (грубо говоря как новый топик на форуме). Т.к мне именно этот протокол и не понятен.

Comment: личный опыт показал что многие вообще не понимают что из себя представляет понятие "протокол". если сильно упростить, то протокол это набор инструкций/правил которые описывают допустимые действия всех кто участвует в процессе обмена данными. в вашем случае для того чтоб 2 или больше клиентов могли общатся друг сдругом вам надо разработать протокол обмена данными. абстрактный пример протокола вам привел @Nofate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В протоколе должны быть предусмотрены команды вроде таких:

- *создать комнату* - регистрируем комнату в некотором списке на сервере;
- *войти в комнату* - приписываем пользователя к комнате (грубо говоря, кладем в `Map<Room, List<User>>`), пригодится и обратный индекс (`Map<User, List<Room>>`);
- *выйти из комнаты* - исключаем пользователя из комнаты;
- *пригласить в комнату* - уведомляем другого пользователя сообщением о существовании комнаты (цель - передать клиенту идентификатор комнаты для подключения);
- *получить список пользователей в комнате*.

Если пользователь может находиться только в одной комнате, просто рассылаем его сообщения всем пользователям в комнате. Если он может сидеть в нескольких комнатах - клиент должен передать серверу идентификатор комнаты (иначе как сервер догадается кому делать рассылку), но после этого сервер должен проверить реально ли пользователь сидит в комнате, прежде чем рассылать сообщение. (Это вообще очень важное правило клиент-серверных систем: не доверять пользователю, проверять приходящие данные)

Кроме того вам нужно определиться, продолжают ли существовать комнаты, когда в них никого нет. Если да - все по выше описанной схеме. Если нет, то создание комнаты должно сразу инициировать вход пользователя в нее, а выход всех пользователей должен приводить к удалению комнаты из списка.

Comment: Согласен, организация комнаты это уже чисто абстрактно-логический уровень протокола. Кажется топикстартер путается [в уровнях организации сети](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%E5%F2%E5%E2%E0%FF_%EC%EE%E4%E5%EB%FC_OSI)

Answer (score 2):

Шлешь в сообщении идентификатор пользователя (если личное сообщение) или канала(комнаты) (если сообщение для всех. 0 - общий канал, например, 1 - какая-то комната и т.д.), я считаю это правильный вариант. А сервер уже смотрит кто сидит в комнате и разошлет им твое сообщение. Вроде все тривиально.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, всё общение от одного клиента к другому должно проходить через сервак. А если так, то что мешает создать какой то список в котором будут храниться клиенты из одной комнаты? И при сабмите сообщения отсылать всем клиентам которые находятся в листе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Моя проблема в том, что я не знаю, как различить клиентов определенной комнаты. В начале думал посылать в каждом сообщение идентификатор комнаты. Но по мне, это крайне неправильный подход.